# How to wait function to finish in for loop js?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a for-loop that iterates through functions and I want this loop to wait untill function is finished to get to the next function. How do I do that?

```
middlewares = []

for (let i in middlewares) {
    middlewares[i]()
}
```

Comment: are the middlewares functions asynchronous or synchronous ?

Comment: if `middlewares[i]` is a synchronous function, so your code is doing excactly what you want it to do. If it's asynchronous, read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) how to handle it.

Comment: We're gonna need more of an example. This code doesn't do anything. If they're async you can chain them with promises.

Comment: Middlewares functions can be synchronous and asynchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution will work if the middlewares functions return a promise when they are asynchronous

```
async function loop(middlewares) {
   for (let fn of middlewares) {
     await fn();
   }
}

loop(middlewares)
  .then(() => console.log("finished");
```

Comment: You don't even have to wrap it in `Promise.resolve()`. `await` does this implicitly for you. You can simply `await fn()`. *"If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise."* - [MDN await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Description)

Answer (score 1):

You can’t as `for` loops are synchronous. I recommend using [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `middlewares` functions async functions. This makes it easier to wait until the function is finished and then move on to the next one. To make an async function is easy: `async function(...) {...}`. Read about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).